# Движение модели самолета вокруг Земного шара

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 3d, моделирование

Необходимо на 3D модели Земли гонять по кругу трехмерную модель самолета. Трек фейковый, не важно где, главное что бы по кругу. Примерно как на изображении. Почитал про физику, и про кватернионы (также про pitch, roll, yaw), пока не особо понял, вернее вообще не въехал. Есть у меня самолетик например нарисованный в 3D Макс, как его установить ровно на треке согласно координатам? И как его вращать? Примеров на C# WinForms, куда можно было бы подглядеть, особо и не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Windows Forms нет никаких средств для работы с 3D-графикой. Самый простой способ сделать это - создать 3D-сцену средствами WPF и подключить ее к Windows Forms с помощью элемента [ElementHost](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=netframework-4.7.2). В WPF трехмерная модель задается как элемент XAML MeshGeometry3D, состоящий из набора треугольников. По конвертации моделей из 3D Max в XAML см. здесь: [XAML exporter for 3D Studio Max](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2009/03/31/daily-tip-how-to-import-3d-model-to-wpf-from-3d-max/).

Пример модели Земли и текстуры земной поверхности можно взять, например, [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2006/06/05/rotating-3d-earth-in-wpf/).

---

Для примера, создадим проект WinForms и добавим в него ссылки на сборки WPF (PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml, WindowsBase).

Добавим в проект файл **Scene.xaml**, описывающий трехмерную сцену: расположение объектов и камеры, освещение, параметры вращения и т.п.

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="black">

   <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="360" To="0" Duration="0:0:15" AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="rotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Viewport3D x:Name="scene3d">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="20" FieldOfView="65" 
                                   LookDirection="0,0,-1" NearPlaneDistance="1" 
                                   Position="0,0,4" UpDirection="0,1,0" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup x:Name="modelgroup">
                        <AmbientLight Color="#ffffffff" />
                        <GeometryModel3D x:Name="earthmodel" >                            
                            <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                <Transform3DGroup>                                    
                                    <RotateTransform3D>
                                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="200" x:Name="rotation" />
                                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                    </RotateTransform3D>
                                </Transform3DGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Добавим файлы **earth.xaml** и **earth.jpg**, содержащие модель и текстуру Земли (XAML не включен в текст ответа из-за размера, см. ссылку на проект ниже).

Добавим модель самолета **plane.xaml**. У меня для примера просто треугольник.

```
<MeshGeometry3D xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1" 
Positions="0.1,0,0 0,-0.04,0 0,0.04,0 " 
TriangleIndices="0 1 2" />
```

Для простоты предположим, что путь самолета является параллелью заданной географической широты. Чтобы не заботится о горизонтальной координате самолета (и о том, попадает ли он в кадр или нет), сделаем его неподвижным и вместо этого будем вращать Землю в противоположном направлении, так что видимый результат будет тем же самым. Наша модель Земли располагается в точке (0;0;0), имеет радиус 1 и ее ось совпадает с осью Y. Ось Z направлена в сторону наблюдателя. Тогда формулы для расчета положения самолета в координатах сцены будут определяться следующими формулами:

> x = 0
>
> y = sin(A)
>
> z = cos(A)

где А - угол, соответствующий географической широте, переведенный в радианы. Например, 0.5*Pi для северного полюса, 0 для экватора, -0.5*Pi для южного полюса.

Добавим код для инициализации 3D-сцены и добавления в нее самолета на заданной широте:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Diagnostics;
//Ссылки: PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml, WindowsBase

namespace WinForms3D
{
    public static class Earth3D
    {
        //Загружает элемент из XAML-файла по указанному пути
        public static object LoadXaml(string path)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            using (sr)
            {
                object el = XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream);
                return el;
            }
        }

        //Создает трехмерную сцену
        public static FrameworkElement BuildModel(double shirota)
        {
            //Загружаем определение сцены
            FrameworkElement scene = LoadXaml("Scene.xaml") as FrameworkElement;                        
            GeometryModel3D earthmodel = (GeometryModel3D)scene.FindName("earthmodel");
            Model3DGroup modelgroup = (Model3DGroup)scene.FindName("modelgroup");

            //Загружаем модель Земли
            Geometry3D earth = LoadXaml("earth.xaml") as Geometry3D;
            earthmodel.Geometry = earth;

            //Задаем текстуру для модели Земли
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("earth.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            DiffuseMaterial mat = new DiffuseMaterial(new ImageBrush(img));
            earthmodel.Material = mat;

            //Загружаем модель самолета
            Geometry3D g = LoadXaml("plane.xaml") as Geometry3D;
            GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D();
            model.Geometry = g;
            model.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
            model.BackMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));

            //Задаем позицию самолета на модели
            double alpha = (Math.PI / 180.0) * shirota; //перевод из градусов в радианы
            model.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(0, Math.Sin(alpha), Math.Cos(alpha) + 0.1);            

            modelgroup.Children.Add(model);
            return scene;
        }
    }
}
```

В форму добавим ElementHost из раздела "Взаимодействие с WPF". Его свойству Child присвоим нашу трехмерную сцену:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms3D
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            elementHost1.Child = Earth3D.BuildModel(30.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит самолет на параллели в 30 градусов северной широты:

[image: 3D Earth]

Полный архив с проектом (VS 2012): https://yadi.sk/d/zxu06TjTMx8bdQ

**Источники**

[WPF - Создание трехмерной сцены](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-3-d-scene)

[WPF - Размещение составного элемента управления WPF в форме Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms)

[Loading XAML XML through runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077318/loading-xaml-xml-through-runtime)

[Rotating 3D earth in WPF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2006/06/05/rotating-3d-earth-in-wpf/)

Comment: Шикарный ответ!!! Огромная вам благодарность!